# Reading entire html file to String?

Tags: java, file-io

Are there better ways to read an entire html file to a single string variable than:

```
    String content = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mypage.html"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content +=str;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's the [`IOUtils.toString(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream)) utility from Apache Commons.

If you're using `Guava` there's also [`Files.readLines(..)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) and [`Files.toString(..)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html).

Comment: The first link is dead

Comment: Both links are dead now.

Answer (score 29):

You should use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mypage.html"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        contentBuilder.append(str);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
String content = contentBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: for me this does't work since the whole html content coming back as a one single string and the in.readLine() just read the whole content for the first call

Comment: how does it know where mypage.html is located?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD you need to pass the relative path to the project root folder. For example, if your mypage.html was located inside the root folder, right next to /src, you can just do "mypage.html" but if you put it in a folder, you'd have to reference that folder too, as in "/myfolder/mypage.html"

Answer (score 7):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).
It's a very strong `HTML parser` for java

Answer (score 6):

As Jean mentioned, using a `StringBuilder` instead of `+=` would be better. But if you're looking for something simpler, Guava, IOUtils, and Jsoup are all good options.

Example with Guava:

```
String content = Files.asCharSource(new File("/path/to/mypage.html"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).read();
```

Example with IOUtils:

```
InputStream in = new URL("/path/to/mypage.html").openStream();
String content;

try {
   content = IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 } finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
 }
```

Example with Jsoup:

```
String content = Jsoup.parse(new File("/path/to/mypage.html"), "UTF-8").toString();
```

**or**

```
String content = Jsoup.parse(new File("/path/to/mypage.html"), "UTF-8").outerHtml();
```

**NOTES:**

> `Files.readLines()` and `Files.toString()`

These are now deprecated as of Guava release version 22.0 (May 22, 2017). 
`Files.asCharSource()` should be used instead **as seen in the example above.** ([version 22.0 release diffs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/diffs/))

> `IOUtils.toString(InputStream)` and `Charsets.UTF_8`

Deprecated as of Apache Commons-IO version 2.5 (May 6, 2016). `IOUtils.toString` should now be passed the `InputStream` **and** the `Charset` as seen in the example above. Java 7's `StandardCharsets` should be used instead of `Charsets` **as seen in the example above.** ([deprecated Charsets.UTF_8](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/Charsets.html#UTF_8))

Answer (score 4):

I prefers using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) :

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Files;
File file = new File("/path/to/file", Charsets.UTF_8);
String content = Files.toString(file);
```

Comment: Note: a ) is missing after the filepath.

Answer (score 3):

For string operations use StringBuilder or StringBuffer classes for accumulating string data blocks. Do not use `+=` operations for string objects. `String` class is immutable and you will produce a large amount of string objects upon runtime and it will affect on performance.

Use `.append()` method of StringBuilder/StringBuffer class instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to retrieve  the html of a webpage using only standard java libraries:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

String urlToRead = "https://google.com";
URL url; // The URL to read
HttpURLConnection conn; // The actual connection to the web page
BufferedReader rd; // Used to read results from the web page
String line; // An individual line of the web page HTML
String result = ""; // A long string containing all the HTML
try {
 url = new URL(urlToRead);
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
 rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  result += line;
 }
 rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(result);
```

---

[SRC](https://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256DC80053681B)

Answer (score 0):

```
 import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
 import java.io.IOException;     
    try {
               var content = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray ( this.getClass().
                        getResource("/index.html")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

//Java 10 Code mentioned above - assuming index.html is available inside resources folder.