# Storing html file in a String in java

Tags: java, html, string, file

I am sending emails using amazon java sdk. I have to send html template as mail. I have written a program for this and it is working fine. But now I am storing the whole html code in a single String. But whenever i need to edit the template, I have to edit the program (I mean the String variable). And also I have to take care the special characters like " \ ...etc in that html code. Please suggest me an elegant way to solve this issue.

Comment: do you mean you have the template hard coded in a java class ? or that you read a file and stiore the content of the file in a String ? i guess the first so just store the html as file and read it when you need it from that file

Comment: @Peter Yes. Noe I have hard coded it inside my java class. I know it is not a good way.

Comment: As Andrey Adamovich said, use template engine. I recommend Freemarker which is easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better and easiest way is reading the html file line by line using simple file reading operation and append this each line to a single String. And also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035316/reading-entire-html-file-to-string) solution (also a better one, if you are ready to add one more library file to your project) from SO.

Answer (score 2):

Use a template engine for that and store your template externally either in class path or on a file system. Here is a question that may help you selecting one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381619/best-template-engine-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Common Lang api's](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) `StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml`, It escapes the characters in a String using HTML entities and return a new escaped `String`, null if null `string` input.

For example:

```
"US" & "UK"
```

becomes:

```
&quot;US&quot; &amp; &quot;UK&quot;.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Apache Velocity Project](http://velocity.apache.org/). You can create template for several things. From it's [user-guide page](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#What_is_Velocity)

> Velocity can be used to generate web pages, SQL, PostScript and other output from templates. It 
>   can be used either as a standalone utility for generating source code and reports, or as an 
>   integrated component of other systems.

You can use a VTL(Velocity Template Language) . A example from above link

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello $customer.Name!
<table>
#foreach( $mud in $mudsOnSpecial )
   #if ( $customer.hasPurchased($mud) )
      <tr>
        <td>
          $flogger.getPromo( $mud )
        </td>
      </tr>
   #end
#end
</table>
```