# How to read html from a file?

Tags: java, html, file, w3c-validation, readfile

I have a file with content:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>     
        <head>      
            <title>Hello, w3c validator!</title>    
        <head>
        <body>      
             <p>Hello again!</p>    
        </body> 
 </html>
```

How to read this file in Java and send to validator-w3c?

Comment: Your question is not very clear? What do you want to do?

Comment: @Kata I think he needs to do a small program in JAva that as input get the HTML files and as output gives the w3c validation output on the files... Am i wong Relrin? HAve you tried something so far?

Comment: is it a requirement to send the html to an online validator ? have you considered using a html parser and the corresponding DTDs and validating yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Java Program that:

1. INPUT: the HTML file
2. Read the HTML file
3. Validate the file (w3c validation)
4. OUTPUT: Validation output

For the point 1 and 2, you can give a loot to another post in SO: [Reading entire html file to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035316/reading-entire-html-file-to-string)

For the point 3, you can check the [Markup Validator Web Service API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html) for the specification of how to contact the w3c HTML validator but this is what they say:

```
Note: Please be considerate in using this shared, free resource. 
Consider Installing your own instance of the validator for smooth and fast operation. 
Excessive use of the W3C Validation Service will be blocked.
```

So my suggestion is to read this article to understand better what you can do and if you can integrate it inside a Java Programa:

[Installation information 
for the W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html)

Comment: I'm trying to use rexsl-w3c, which send data to this site. If a get information, about what my page is invalid - print errors, but, always get "0 0" at console application, and i don't know why...