# how to send email with html content via mailsender java

Tags: java, html, jsp, email

Im using mailsender method to send email to user from the system, right now im successfully send a basic email with hardcode html tag in java code. But how can i send an email with html file instead of hardcode html tag in java code? Sorry im new for this.

### Example current code index.jsp

```
  /*---------------EMAIl---------------*/
       FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/test/config.prop");
       Properties prop    = new Properties();
       prop.load(is);

       String FROM      = prop.getProperty("email");
       String TO        = EMAIL;//EMAIL; 
       String border    = "0";
       String width1    = "100%";
       String face      = "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif";
       String size1     = "2";
       String size2     = "1";

       if(!TO.equals(""))
       { 
           String SUBJECT2 = "e-cover MyPolicy";

           String BODY  = "<html><body>"+
                  "<table width="+width1+" border="+border+">"+
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">Thank you for signing up, you're almost done!</font></td></tr>"+             
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">&nbsp;</td></tr>"+
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">Please click this link to activate your account:<br/></font></td></tr>"+                           
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">https://e-cover.com.my/verify/verification.jsp<br/></font></td></tr>"+                           
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">&nbsp;</td></tr>"+
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">(If clicking the link did not work, try copying and pasting it into your browser.)<br/></font></td></tr>"+                           
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size1+">&nbsp;</td></tr>"+
                  "<tr><td width="+width1+"><font face="+face+" size="+size2+"><i>**Please do not reply to this email as it was automatically generated.**</i></font></td></tr>"+                   
                  "</table>"+
                  "</body></html>";
            try
            {
                mailsender.setFrom(FROM.trim());             
                mailsender.sendIt(TO.trim(), SUBJECT2, BODY);
                System.out.println("Sending......");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
```

I have another html file. But how can i to apply this html file content in my index.jsp. not attachment. is the content of the html. Any help will be appreciated.

### example html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>MyPolicy</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
 <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
    <td>
       <img src="http://www.test.com/logo.png"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to attachments, try referring to `MimeMessageHelper`. You can combine it with `InputStreamSource` to attach the file to the email. Is that what you meant or were you talking about having the image embedded in the email itself?

**Edit after comments:**

There are a few ways of reading files. The most common way I've seen people do is to use `BufferedReader` or `FileReader`.

But if you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035316/reading-entire-html-file-to-string), you'll be able to see from Johan Sjöberg's post that you can use Apache Commons or Guava to have a cleaner import of the HTML file as a string. I'm not exactly sure if those are transferable to JSP (you can test it out) but if anything, you can use the earlier methods that I mentioned above.

So you would call:

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
```

And in your body, you would use something like:

```
<%
    ...
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.html"));    //make sure the path is correct regarding the server
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    String BODY = sb.toString();
    try
    {
    ...
%>
```

Comment: nonono .. not attachment .. what i was trying to do is i want to display the another html file content in my java file ..  but i have no idea how to insert it ..

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your question. In that case, couldn't you try to read in the html file as a string then insert that into the body of the mail?

Comment: No worries dude, Yes, that's the point how can i read that html file as a string ? and past to this jsp file ...

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if that answers your question.