# How to convert string from [object HTMLDocument] in android or java

Tags: javascript, java, android, gecko, html-rendering

I am developing a customized gecko powered android browser. I want to print the source code in console.

When I try to print it shows `[object HTMLDocument]`.

The code is given below :

```
 function onPageLoad(event) {
   // the target is an HTMLDocument
   let contentDocument = event.target;
 let browser = BrowserApp.getBrowserForDocument(contentDocument);
   console.log("Page loaded: " + browser.contentTitle);
   console.log("Page loaded content: " + browser.contentDocument);

 }
```

The output is Page loaded content: `[object HTMLDocument]`

I want to print the source code in `[object HTMLDocument]`.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see. Try:

```
let contentDocument = event.target;
console.log("Page loaded: " + contentDocument.title);
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(contentDocument);
console.log("Page loaded content: " + s);
```

This worked for me at least (if I understand correctly what you want to print that is).

Comment: The output shows "Page loaded content: undefined". The codes are written in javascript file.

Comment: which is the import file for XMLSerializer in android studio.  I have got an error is JavaScript Error: "ReferenceError: XMLSerializer is not defined"

Comment: I think it is "import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;", hope it works!

Comment: It helped me with a JavaScript import, so thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting it to a String? For example, console.log("Page loaded: " + String(browser.contentTitle));

Comment: The result is shown as "Page loaded: [object HTMLDocument]". I want to print the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HTMLEditorKit tmp = new HTMLEditorKit(); 
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) tmp.createDefaultDocument(); 
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
tmp.write(writer, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
String s = writer.toString();
console.log(s);
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Not getting the result. s is not printing.

Comment: ok, so try checking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035316/reading-entire-html-file-to-string - this StringBuilder answer worked for me once :)

Comment: Not getting any results.

Answer (score 0):

Put `,` instead of `+` in `console.log()` function as `console.log()` also support object. Just you need to separate by comma.

```
console.log("Page loaded: " , browser.contentTitle);
console.log("Page loaded content: " , browser.contentDocument);
```

Comment: The output is
 I/Gecko: console.log: Page loaded:  Asset Test 
I/Gecko: console.log: Page loaded content:  HTMLDocument {"location":{"href":"resource://android/assets/test.html","origin":"resource://android","protocol":"resource:","username":"","password":"","host":"android","hostname":"android","port":"","pathname":"/assets/test.html","search":"","hash":""}}

Comment: using comma is not possible.

Comment: It's just showing what it contains. `browser.contentTitle` and `browser.contentDocument` do not contains any source code. I guess  `event.target` would give you source code.

Comment: Here is the source code   
https://github.com/ncalexan/geckobrowser-gradle   
pls help me

Comment: I want to highlight phone numbers like skype "click to call" service. How it possible using this code. pls help me